# Android приложение вылетает после запуска

Tags: android, android-gradle

Скомпилировал приложение Android на api 29. После теста на телефоне во время запуска оно сразу сворачивается, но в шторке оно запущено, при открытии так же себя ведет, как исправить?

Логи

```
E/FirebaseInstanceId: Topic sync or token retrieval failed on hard failure exceptions: AUTHENTICATION_FAILED. Won't retry the operation
E/chromium: [ERROR:filesystem_posix.cc(89)] stat /data/user/0/com.bestweby.enewz/cache/WebView/Crashpad: No such file or directory (2)
    [ERROR:filesystem_posix.cc(62)] mkdir /data/user/0/com.bestweby.enewz/cache/WebView/Crashpad: No such file or directory (2)

2021-05-26 23:56:00.023 8262-8262/com.sandrey.wylsmart E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sandrey.wylsmart, PID: 8262
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.sandrey.wylsmart.adapter.viewpager.TemplateSliderAdapter.instantiateItem(TemplateSliderAdapter.java:49)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:1010)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1158)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1622)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:735)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:481)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout.onMeasure(CollapsingToolbarLayout.java:420)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout.onMeasure(AppBarLayout.java:264)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:733)
        at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$BaseBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1161)
        at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$Behavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:842)
        at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$BaseBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:869)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:803)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
        at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1119)
        at com.sandrey.wylsmart.customview.CustomDrawerLayout.onMeasure(CustomDrawerLayout.java:32)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:742)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24530)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3006)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1833)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2122)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1721)
2021-05-26 23:56:00.024 8262-8262/com.sandrey.wylsmart E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7598)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:966)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:790)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:725)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:951)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
2021-05-26 23:56:00.232 8262-8486/com.sandrey.wylsmart W/andrey.wylsmar: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
2021-05-26 23:56:00.380 8262-8273/com.sandrey.wylsmart I/andrey.wylsmar: Background young concurrent copying GC freed 12936(621KB) AllocSpace objects, 20(2100KB) LOS objects, 22% free, 5468KB/7040KB, paused 98.628ms total 1.014s
2021-05-26 23:56:00.432 8262-8262/com.sandrey.wylsmart I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 8262 SIG: 9
```

Исходники приложения...

https://github.com/tommy-maulana/enewz

Comment: Для этого есть логи и Logcat, чтобы понять в чём дело. Посмотрите и исправьте сами, либо добавьте сюда

Comment: Не подумал добавил

Comment: Ну так почитай в чем там ошибка и загугли ее. Сейчас тут советы могут быть только такие: болит нога? ну отрежь ее.

Answer (score 0):

Файл `TemplateSliderAdapter.java`, строка №49 попытка взять элемент `ArrayList` с индексом 0, при нулевом размере массива.

Научитесь в конце концов читать логи:

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
> at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
> at

> com.sandrey.wylsmart.adapter.viewpager.TemplateSliderAdapter.instantiateItem(TemplateSliderAdapter.java:49)